# Not able to test HUAWEI FIDO facial authentication feature

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Integrated FIDO facial authentication, he had followed the below link for integration.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/integrating-bioauthn-0000001077711576-V1

He is getting the error “FACE_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE”  in P40 pro device.

Can you please suggest some device names that has “authentication hardware available”?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link for facial authentication features supporting devices:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/integrating-bioauthn-0000001077711576-V1

Only EMUI 10 (API level 29) and later versions support 3D facial authentication. In addition, the device hardware must support 3D facial authentication. Currently, only Mate 20 Pro and Mate 30 Pro support 3D facial authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Please find supported device model from the FAQ https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/faq-0000001096426805-V1

Only EMUI 10 (API Level 29) and later versions support 3D facial authentication. In addition, the device hardware must support 3D facial authentication. Such devices include Mate 20 Pro, Mate 20 RS, Mate 30 Pro, Mate 30 RS, Mate 40 Pro, Mate 40 Pro+, and Mate 40 RS. For details, please refer to parameters of each device model.